# jQuery .html() and inject inline CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, email

The following code pulls HTML from a table and injects the contents into HTML email.

```
var content = $j('#product_comparison').html();
```

The problem with this approach is that the HTML email loses its styling because the original table references an external stylesheet and my understanding of HTML email is that all styles should be inline and not referenced externally or within a `<style>` tag.

Are there any Javascript / jQuery methods that can create the HTML with inline styles included so the result would appear correctly in a HTML email message?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? And styles are not referenced by a `<script>` tag but a `<style>` tag. You can use the `<style>` tag in email templates.

Comment: Apologies, I meant `<style>` - will update the original question.

Comment: The `<table>` itself is quite complicated, with `odd` and `even` classes on the `<tr>`, background colours and various styles

Comment: There are known solution to normally retrieve all the CSS applied to an element. See the stackoverflow topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element. Then you could add it to your email with inline CSS in the forwarded HTML for ex.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a crude but quick way of achieving this, you can do as follows to set the style attribute of one specific element to all its computed style:

```
$('#my-div').css(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('my-div')));
```

Although this will give you **all** style properties for that item.

Of course, you cannot simply use the `.html()` method for this, you'll need to clone each element individually.

http://jsfiddle.net/QfN6N/1/

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the HTML out, paste into the tool linked to below, preceded by a `<link>` to the CSS file and it will inline all the relevant CSS automatically.

[MailChimp CSS Inliner](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css)

Hope this helps.